# What are "Honey Bubbles" and how are they made?

Tags: dessert, food-identification, japanese-cuisine

[image: Honey Bubbles at Kichisen]

I recently had the thrilling privilige of eating a Kaiseki meal at Kichisen in Kyoto. One of the meal's many highlights was a desert course consisting of a large citrus fruit filled with jelly and topped with what the apprentice chef serving us called "honey bubbles" (see the attached picture). The bubbles tasted sweet and did not pop of their own accord but turned to air when consumed.

Does anyone know how this foam is made and what it is made of? It was delicious, and if I could even come close to replicating it at home I would love to give it a go.

Comment: Sounds nice! Out of curiosity, what flavour was the jelly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with an air pump, egg white powder and xanthan gum :)

http://www.molecularrecipes.com/culinary-foams-class/bubbles-air-pump/

[image: Bubbles]

> The “bubbles with air pump” technique consists of injecting air using a fish tank air pump into a liquid with some viscosity. It works great with light syrups and juices by just adding a little egg white powder and Xanthan gum.

Otherwise check out airs: http://www.molecularrecipes.com/category/emulsification/airs-emulsification/

[image: Airs]

> Airs are usually made by adding soy lecithin powder to a liquid and incorporating air using an immersion blender on the surface of the liquid.

Airs will make smaller bubbles, but you can do it with an immersion blender (stick blender) so you don’t need to find an air pump.