# Honey bubbles taste question

Tags: honey, tasting

What do honey bubbles taste like?
I'm asking because I've got almost no sense of smell or taste myself.
The answer is probably obvious though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about what's [pictured in this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/79015/1672), they're basically just bubbles made out of honey, so they'll taste like honey - sweet, and maybe with some fragrance depending on what kind of honey it is.